# How to choose a range of columns in R

Tags: r, median

I have some data and just want to calculate `mean`, `sd`, `var` and so on. My problem are not the functions but the columns, I just can't seem to figure out how to choose them.

So the first column includes the names of the animals and column 2 to 11 my numeric data. 
Column names are `X1` to `X10`.
I have lots of `NA` in my data.

I can easily calculate it for each row but when I combine them I always get

> Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

So for example for mean and one column I tried (+ it worked)

```
mean(WLD1$X1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

for column 2 to 11 I tried:

```
mean(WLD1[,c(2:11)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

also tried:

```
lapply(WLD1[,2:11], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Also tried it with `X1:X10`.
I guess it's pretty simple but I'm just stuck on it. Really thankful for any help.

Comment: `colMeans(WLD1[2:11], na.rm=TRUE)`. For other statistics, `apply(WLD1[2:11], 2, var)` or `sd`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use apply function. What the apply function does is takes a function (required computation) and applies to each element either column wise or row wise for a DataFrame or a matrix. The row wise and column wise settings are encoded by the MARGIN= parameter and the actual computation that you want to do is encoded by FUN= (which stands for function obviously). So if you want to feed your one row at a time inside the intended function/computation then you will choose MARGIN=1 otherwise you will choose MARGIN=2 (which means one column at a time will be fed into the function).
Since in your case you want to compute the mean, sd and var for column numbers 2 to 11, you will do it in three steps and you are right we will have MARGIN=2 for all the three statments but FUN= will keep changing. Below is the code.

```
Mean_of_2_to_11_Column <- apply(WLD1[,2:11], MARGIN=2, FUN=mean)
SD_of_2_to_11_Column <- apply(WLD1[,2:11], MARGIN=2, FUN=sd)
Var_of_2_to_11_Column <- apply(WLD1[,2:11], MARGIN=2, FUN=var)
```

Let me know if any thing here I said is not clear to you. All the best

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)
mydatabase %>% map_if(is.numeric, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This will calculate the mean of all the numeric columns of your database while ignoring NA values.

Comment: for sd, var and so on juste change "mean" to the desired mesure.